# Trying to return up a recursive combinations function without getting 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, combinations

When I call this with [1,2,3,4], it returns undefined and I'm not understanding why.  The goal is for it to return true if any combination of numbers in the array add up to the maximum number in the array, and false if it's not possible.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 

  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1);
  var sum = function(arr) { return arr.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b; }); };

  function combos(arr) {

    var f = function(prefix, arr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var clone = prefix.slice(0);
        clone.push(arr[i]);
        if (sum(clone) == max) { return true; }
        return f(clone, arr.slice(i+1));
      }
    }
    return f([], arr);
  }

  return combos(arr); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` is returning `undefined` when it is called with an empty `arr`! You will need to explicitly `return false` if none of the tests in the loop returned from the function. And you must not `return false` on the first occasion of the loop, but break only when you found `true` and continue the loop elsewhile.

To fix this, you'd have something like

```
function combos(arr) {
  function f(prefix, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var clone = prefix.slice(0);
      clone.push(arr[i]);
      if (sum(clone) == max) return true;
      if (f(clone, arr.slice(i+1))) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return f([], arr);
}
```

However, also your recursion scheme with the loop looks a bit complicated. I would rather go with the naive enumeration of the "binary tree", where the nodes of each level decide whether the current item will be included in the to-be-tested subset:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1);
  var sum = function(arr) { return arr.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b; }, 0); };

  function f(subset, arr) {
     return arr.length 
          ? f(subset, arr.slice(1)) || f(subset.concat([arr[0]]), arr.slice(1))
          : sum(subset) == max
  }
  return f([], arr); 
}
```

Comment: Hey Bergi, this looks awesome but when I try the second one (after adding a starting value on the reduce function) I get maximum call stack size exceeded.  I don't see why the first block of code, or original design is "flawed".  Thanks for your awesome explanations

Comment: Oops, it must stop recursion when `arr` is empty. Fixed now.

Comment: OK, your attempt of recursion will actually work. I was very confused by the loop and thought initially that it would enumerate some "prefices" (subsets, actually) multiple times or even skip them. However, after thinking it through again, it might even benefit and have lesser recursive calls than the naive solution, which simply enumerates the binary tree or all possible subsets.

Comment: That is a beautiful function :')! (btw, I think `array.length` should be `arr.length`?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't test all the possible combination.

Here you will test 1+2+3, 2+3, 3 but never 1+3.

Do you really want to have a recursive function here ?
There may be some more simple way to find that.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1);

    var res = arr.filter(function(num, idx) {
        var combination = false;
        // Check all combination non previously tested
        for (var i = idx; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (num + arr[i+1] === max) {
                combination = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return combination;
    });
    return res.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: But your code is only testing combinations of 2 items out of the array, not all possible ones?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `f` function is not ever hitting the 
`if (sum(clone) == max) { return true; }`
line of code so it will just keep recursively calling until arr.length == 0 and it will return undefined.

Your variables torf and results are unused, maybe you forgot to do something with them?

Comment: No they were just left over.  So what's the fix? I tried breaking the for loop but that didn't work either.  I guess if the first set of calls down to arr.length == 0 returns undefined then the for should continue with i = 1 on the array with [1], but im lost for how to do this